# Access TextBox Control In ListView Control

Tags: c#, asp.net

How to access "TextBox" control inside "ListView" Control ?

For example I want to use `this.AddCommentTextbox.Text` property in code-behind.

aspx code:

```
 <asp:ListView ID="PostsListView" runat="server" DataSourceID="EntityDataSourcePosts">
   <ItemTemplate>
     <asp:TextBox Text="active" ID="AddCommentTextbox" runat="server"  TextMode="MultiLine" Height="100" Width="370"></asp:TextBox>
   </ItemTemplate>
 </asp:ListView>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could try something like this:

```
TextBox tmpControl = (TextBox)PostsListView.FindControl("AddCommentTextbox");
```

then you can do something with the tmpControl.text

Hope that helps.