# Find TextBox Control Inside ListView Control

Tags: c#, asp.net

How to access or found "TextBox" control inside "ListView" Control ?

For example I want to use `this.AddCommentTextbox.Text` property in code-behind of this aspx page.

aspx page code:

```
 <asp:ListView ID="PostsListView" runat="server" DataSourceID="EntityDataSourcePosts">
   <ItemTemplate>
     <asp:TextBox Text="active" ID="AddCommentTextbox" runat="server"  TextMode="MultiLine" Height="100" Width="370"></asp:TextBox>
   </ItemTemplate>
 </asp:ListView>
```

Comment: ..or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15055797/access-textbox-control-in-listview-control

Answer (score 0):

Simply loop through items of the ListView and then either use `FindControl("AddCommentTextbox")` or loop through controls to find if a control is of type `TextBox`.

Comment: Can you show some sample code of this only to see some simple example ?

Answer (score 0):

```
TextBox commentTextBox = (TextBox)PostsListView.FindControl("AddCommentTextbox");
```